# MySQL Query Rollup

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a problem. My MySQL query doesn't work. How could I fix this ?
my query

```sql
select state, city, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * sales.quantity) as profit 
from products, sales
where sales.product_id = products.product_id
group by rollup (state, city)
order by state, city;
```

my error

```sql
11:39:12    select state, city, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * sales.quantity) as profit  from products, sales where sales.product_id = products.product_id group by rollup (state, city) order by state, city   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(state, city) order by state, city' at line 4  0.000 sec
```

my schema

```sql
-- Create some tables and insert some rows.
create table products (product_id integer, wholesale_price real);
insert into products (product_id, wholesale_price) values 
    (1, 1.00),
    (2, 2.00);

create table sales (product_id integer, retail_price real, 
    quantity integer, city varchar, state varchar);
insert into sales (product_id, retail_price, quantity, city, state) values 
    (1, 2.00,  1, 'SF', 'CA'),
    (1, 2.00,  2, 'SJ', 'CA'),
    (2, 5.00,  4, 'SF', 'CA'),
    (2, 5.00,  8, 'SJ', 'CA'),
    (2, 5.00, 16, 'Miami', 'FL'),
    (2, 5.00, 32, 'Orlando', 'FL'),
    (2, 5.00, 64, 'SJ', 'PR');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select state, city, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * 
sales.quantity) as profit 
from products, sales
where sales.product_id = products.product_id
group by state, city WITH ROLLUP
order by state, city;
```

You can see [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-rollup) the ROLL UP behaviour